# Why chrome detects simple batch file as virus

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, cmd, certificate

I have some simple batch script. Converted it to exe to share them on my blog post. But when i try to download them Google chrome and fire fox detect them as virus.Even i tried to share them as .bat file but still same result.

do i need get Code Signing certificate for simple batch script? Is there any other way? 
I do not want to use any rar or zip file.

Comment: Can you edit and post the source code of this batch ?

Comment: If you are using a "Batch to Exe" program, the resulting Exe files are typically flagged as a virus. In general, they just wrap the batch file in a self-extracting zip file. Some may be a bit more advanced but typically this is the methodology.

Comment: I tried many simple bat file as well.... but still getting same result.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file to `.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

Due to security policies Google refuses to read a batch file. If you want to transfer or append the same, try renaming it to a .txt /Hope that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it, it's just Chrome's anti-virus. This happened on my batch file website, too, but sometimes it does not happen! :p

As far as I know, there isn't a way to prevent it, apart from putting in a zip folder. On my website, I have 2 download links per download; one in a zip file and one not.

Hope this helped!