# How to manipulate Excel file on the client side

Tags: javascript, php, excel

I´m new to php and javascript, so i'm not even sure i can properly expose my case.

I have a php form where the client selects options on his browser.

On submit, a need the client browser to download an excel file from another domain (i have no control on the 2nd server response).

It must be done on the client side because only the user has access to the 2nd domain (inside a on-premisses network or from the internet with a VPN).

I managed to force the download with the following javascript:

```
function download(dataurl,filename) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = dataurl;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(dataurl);
    a.remove();
}
download(url,filename);
```

The filename does nothing, as the file is saved with the name sent by the server.

After the file is downloaded, i still need to rename and move it to a specific network directory (only acessible by the client).

I can´t use js fetch because the browser blocks the download with CORS.

I'm not even sure if this is possible due to security reasons.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: only way to make it work is enable CORS without it, you are forced to download and reupload.

Comment: I've already tried to enable CORS but the fetch returns an empty corrupted excel file. I can´t use a proxy to workaround CORS because the proxy server doesn't have access to server 2. Fetch allows me to rename the file but doesn't solve the problem of having to move the downloaded file afterwards. And there is an additional problem, in some cases i have to change the excel file column headers (first row) before sending it to the network directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a dirty workaround, how about generating a .bat file with the appropriate DOS copy commands?  If your user is happy to download and execute the file, it might do the job!

I've done something similar with a web app that generates commands for a local macro program.

For example:
You might save the following to copy the file to the correct directory

```
copy c:\\path\to\download\file.xls n:\\path\to\networked\destination
```

or you could make use of built in windows commands to handle the file download

```
curl.exe -0 c:\\path\to\download\file.xls https://domain_with_file.com/file.xls
```

This isn't an ideal way of doing things though, and it looks as if any batch files downloaded might be flagged up as potential virus threats.

Comment: Interesting idea, might make it simpler for the user. Just bear in mind that some browsers are not keen on this - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485804/why-chrome-detects-simple-batch-file-as-virus

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the .bat code? I'm sorry, i'm very new to all this stuff.

Comment: I've added a couple of examples, but I think your IE only ActiveX solution is a far better way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately activex doesn't support the RemoveDuplicates method that is crucial for my project.
So i've tried a different approach: Excel Javascript API to build a Office Add-in for the users to click after opening the downloaded file.
Again, the Excel Javascript API doesn't support the SaveAs method that is obviosly needed.
So now i'm building a VSOT add-in for Excel in C# that apparently supports all the necessary methods.

Answer (score 1):

> "i still need to rename and move it to a specific network directory"

...you can't do that from JavaScript, JavaScript running in a browser has no access to the filesystem of the device it's running on, for security reasons.

All you can do is give the instructions about what they need to do. If that's not satisfactory, then you would need to implement this project as a desktop application, rather than a web application.

Comment: I understand what you mean but i'm precisely trying to move from a MS Access distributed executable to the web. I guess it's not a good idea after all. Still, i find it a bit hard to believe that, with so many technologies available, there's no workaround for this. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: There is no workaround because it's a security restriction, not a technical limitation. If workarounds for security restrictions exist, we call them vulnerabilities instead! And we really hope they don't exist, otherwise any malicious website could start messing with your filesystem

Comment: I think yote options are a) stick with Access ( I agree, not a good option), b) rewrite this as a desktop application, or c) host your application within the user's domain so that the server side code can directly download the Excel file itself and can directly copy it to the network share as well, without resorting to JavaScript. IMHO option c seems the obvious one, but perhaps you have some other limitation which would prevent this.

Comment: I suppose there's also theoretically option d) - allow your current server to connect to the user's VPN and become part of that network. That might not be acceptable to the managers of that network though.

Comment: I agree that option C seems to be the best solution. I've asked the IT guys if that's ok with them. Let's wait for their verdict.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution (IE only with appropriate internet options settings):

```
function test() {
    /* global ActiveXObject*/
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = true; //optional
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\file1.xlsx");
}
```

From here, i believe i can do pretty much what i want.